# Can we use both system proxy and NSURLSessionConfiguration proxy at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, nsurlsession

looks like only one is taking effect.

> The system proxy is specified in Settings-Wifi-HttpProxy.
>
> The in-app proxy is specified with:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];

NSMutableDictionary *proxyDict= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[proxyDict setObject: @1 forKey:@"HTTPSEnable"];

[proxyDict setObject: proxyIP forKey:@"HTTPSProxy"];
[proxyDict setObject: @80 forKey:@"HTTPSPort"];
configuration.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;
```

how can we use both?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the proxy dictionary specified in the session supersedes the system proxy dictionary for all requests made in that session.

If you want to modify the existing configuration (e.g. to add an HTTPS proxy where only an HTTP proxy currently exists), you would need to start by obtaining the system-provided proxy list using `SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies` and then modify it.

If you're trying to chain proxies, I'm not aware of any mechanism for doing that other than constructing the proxy URLs manually.  I'm fairly certain that there's no system-provided mechanism for doing it, because that isn't the sort of configuration that would typically be used.

If your app is doing something unusual, such as using an proxy built into your app that does something special and needs to then forward non-matching requests to the system proxy, then your app's built-in proxy should just re-make the requests in a different session so that any system-provided proxies will be respected.

Comment: Yes, I want to chain proxies. In Java, it can be done pure programmatically by using both System.setProperty() and httpClient, one proxy for each. In iOS, however, looks like there is no such API to set an app-wide proxy.